# Unexpected end of statement

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting over and over the following message error "Unexpected end of statement in the line 2" I can't see any thing wrong with it? What's I'm doing wrong ..

```
Sub Main()
  Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
  Dim match As Match = regex.Match("Dot 77 Perls")
  If match.Success Then
      MessageBox.Show(match.Value)
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing VB.NET syntax with VBScript, the code above should be written like so:

```
Dim regex
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

  regex.Pattern = "\d+"

  If regex.Test("Dot 77 Perls") Then
      WScript.Echo regex.Execute("Dot 77 Perls")(0)
  End If
```

More information on the VBScript Regular Expression engine can be found on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic2)

Comment: See edit above, should be `RegExp` not `Regex` - I missed that initially

Comment: Are you actually writing this in VBA or in Visual Studio?

Comment: Same error .. No, I'm using simple text editor. I don't have access to VS. I'm just trying to create some simple scripts for Outlook

Comment: If you're using a text editor then this isn't VBA, it's VBScript - There's a huge difference which explains the errors. For future reference, VB.NET, VBScript and VBA are entirely separate languages.

Comment: Yes, it's VBScript. Sorry for the confusion. I fixed it by using    Set regex = New RegExp. Please could you update your answer so I will accept it.

Comment: You also don't have to use `CreateObject` as `RegExp` is built-in to VBScript since version 5. Just use `Set regex = New RegExp`.

Comment: @Lankymart I know - just left it there for compatibility, my previous revision included both early-binding and late-binding options (albeit for VBA, not VBScript)